# Invalid Pointer Operation on TObjectList.DisposeOf

Tags: oop, delphi, tobjectlist

Hello folks and sorry if this is a duplicate but my specific issue I haven't seen answered anywhere yet.
I have an "Invalid Pointer Operation" when I try to free an ObjectList created at runtime at the following lines:

```
  Prods := TItemProcedimento.Create(DM.FDQ).lerProdutos;
  Prods.DisposeOf; // <- Invalid Pointer Operation at 2nd iteration
```

So, here's my classes:

```
unit uItemProcedimento;

interface
[...]

type
  TItemProcedimento = class
[...]
public
    constructor Create(DataSet: TFDQuery);
    function lerProdutos: TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>;
[...]

constructor TItemProcedimento.Create(DataSet: TFDQuery);
begin
  FDataSet := DataSet;
end;

function TItemProcedimento.lerProdutos: TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>;
begin
  Result := TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>.Create;
  try
    FDataSet.Close;
    FDataSet.SQL.Clear;
    FDataSet.SQL.Add('SELECT *');
    FDataSet.SQL.Add('FROM Produto p');
    FDataSet.SQL.Add('JOIN ItensProcedimento IP on p.PRO_ID = IP.PRO_ID');
    FDataSet.SQL.Add('ORDER BY p.PRO_Nome');
    FDataSet.Open;
    while not FDataSet.Eof do
    begin
      PRO_ID := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRO_ID').AsInteger;
      PRO_Rendimento := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRO_Rendimento').AsInteger;
      PRO_Nome := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRO_Nome').AsString;
      PRO_Tipo := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRO_Tipo').AsInteger;
      PRO_Custo := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRO_Custo').AsFloat;
      PRO_Potencia := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRO_Potencia').AsFloat;
      IPR_Uso := FDataSet.FieldByName('IPR_Uso').AsFloat;
      Result.Add(self);
      FDataSet.Next;
    end;
  finally
    FDataSet.Close;
  end;
```

The weirdest thing about this is that I have another class with the exact same behaviour and the method works without issues. Yes I am creating the object and immediately destroying it to test if I'm destroying it correctly.
In another class I have another example with the same code, but this time it works without errors

```
 test := TMyClass.Create(DM.FDQ).lerTeste;
 test.DisposeOf;
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? This test code is running before the current code btw, maybe its related?

UPDATE:
By applying the changes that Remy Lebeau suggested I managed to add properly the items to the list and dispose them so this particular part of the code has no leaks. But in another part of the code I have an ObjectList leak that I have no idea on how to fix.

Inside my class I have a property that is a TObjectList property, I have a method that checks if the list is assigned, if not, it creates it and returns it to whoever is calling the list.

```
[...]
type
  TProcedimento = class
  private
  [...]
    FPRC_Produtos: TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>;
  public
  [...]
  function getPRC_Produtos: TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>;
  function criaProcedimentos: TObjectList<TProcedimento>;
  [...]

function TProcedimento.GetPRC_Produtos: TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>;
begin
  if not Assigned(FPRC_Produtos) then
    FPRC_Produtos:= TObjectList<TItemProcedimento>.Create;
  result := FPRC_Produtos;
end;

function TProcedimento.criaProcedimentos: TObjectList<TProcedimento>;
var
  IPR: TItemProcedimento;
  Procedimento: TProcedimento;
  ds: TFDQuery;
begin
  result := TObjectList<TProcedimento>.Create;
  ds := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  ds.Connection := FDataSet.Connection;
  IPR := TItemProcedimento.Create(ds);
  try
    FDataSet.Close;
    FDataSet.Open('SELECT * FROM Procedimento');
    while not FDataSet.Eof do
    begin
      Procedimento := TProcedimento.Create(FDataSet);
      Procedimento.PRC_ID := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRC_ID').AsInteger;
      Procedimento.PRC_Nome := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRC_Nome').AsString;
      Procedimento.PRC_Duracao := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRC_Duracao')
        .AsDateTime;
      Procedimento.PRC_Preco := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRC_Preco').AsCurrency;
      Procedimento.PRC_Custo := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRC_Custo').AsCurrency;
      Procedimento.PRC_Consumo := FDataSet.FieldByName('PRC_Consumo').AsFloat;
      Procedimento.FPRC_Produtos := IPR.getItensProcedimento(FPRC_ID);
      result.Add(Procedimento);
      FDataSet.Next;
    end;
  finally
    FDataSet.Close;
    IPR.DisposeOf;
    ds.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

I then use this property in a for-in loop to feed a list with the procs in my database

```
procedure TKBForm1.CarregaProcedimento;
var
  Procedimento: TProcedimento;
  Procs: TObjectList<TProcedimento>;
  [...]
begin
  Procs := TProcedimento.Create(DM.FDQ).criaProcedimentos;
  try
    LV_Procedimento.Items.Clear;
    LV_Procedimento.BeginUpdate;
    for Procedimento in Procs do
    begin
      with LV_Procedimento.Items.Add do
      [...]
  finally
    Procs.DisposeOf;
    Procedimento.GetPRC_Produtos.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

But there's still leaks happening after this part runs:

```
73 - 88 bytes: TProcedimento x 1, TItemProcedimento x 2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably Result.Add(self); is the culprit. You are adding same object multiple times to the object list. When you free list object is being destroyed multiple times. You should create new object for every item you are adding to the list.

Comment: Well, on debug side it worked fine: My database I have 4 items in it and when I run this code it successfuly created only 1 ObjectList and 4 items in that list.
Also I have the exact same code in another class and there it doesn't throw the invalid pointer error, which is confusing me

Comment: @Mobiusone but those 4 list items are pointing at only 1 `TItemProcedimento` object in memory (`Self`). You need to create 4 distinct `TItemProcedimento` objects, eg have your `while` loop do this instead: `var NewItem: TItemProcedimento; ... while not FDataSet.Eof do begin NewItem := TItemProcedimento.Create; try NewItem.PRO_ID := ...; ... Result.Add(NewItem); except NewItem.Free; raise; end; FDataSet.Next; end;`

Comment: Ok, that worked. And I don't have to worry about destroying them because the ObjectList will handle that for me right?

Comment: @Mobiusone yes, because its `OwnsObjects` property defaults to true.

Comment: Thanks, but I found out that I have a memory leak after fixing that part and I don't know how to solve it. I updated the post above with the issue, if it should be made in another post lemme know and I'll fix it

Comment: @Mobiusone your really messing things up. Using local variabels which point to a single entry and also use the same object to create a list of similar objects. You should really more basically. Define the object class with just the properties you need, when having a list of those objects. Then create a  ‘class function’ to return als list of object using TObjectList. This way you wont need to create an instance of your item object!

Comment: Yeah I made it work using class procedures. Now I'm leak-free. Managed to achieve the result before your comment tho, but thanks for pointing it out. Sometimes we just need to scrap it all and begin again to find the simple solutions, worked for me at least